# Getting new access token using @azure/msal-node

Tags: node.js, azure-ad-msal

[cache object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEguS.png)

```js
const cca = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication({
        auth: {
          clientId: 'dummy data',
          clientSecret: 'dummy data',
          tokenCache: cache.storage.cache,
          // tokenCache: tokenCache,
        }
      })
      const account = await promiseConnection.query(accountQuery)
      const buffer1 = Buffer.from(account[0][0].account, 'base64').toString()
      const stringAccount = buffer1.toString();
      const accountObject = JSON.parse(stringAccount)

      // console.log(accountObject)
    try {
      const result = await cca.acquireTokenSilent({
        scopes: ['calendars.readWrite'],
        account: accountObject,
      }).then(result => {
        const accessToken = result.accessToken
        console.log(accessToken)
      })
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }`
```

I stored the token cache in a database and tried using it in the acquireTokenSilent() method.
I see the refresh token in the cache object, bit the error is:

```
  errorCode: 'no_tokens_found',
  errorMessage: 'No refresh token found in the cache. Please sign-in.',
```

Any advice?

Comment: sorry for the bad formatting of the top half of the code

Comment: Is the token cache properly populated in the example above? Is the user logging in with the exact same scopes/account when you're hitting the error?

Comment: I used the serialize method of the TokenCache Class to serialize the cache and it formatted it according to msal-node's cache schema. I deserialized it into a javascript object and passed it to aquireTokenSilent but it still did not find the refresh token.